Why does my apartment's water pressure drop so dramatically?
Apologies in advance if this isn't the right place to ask this question (or if I haven't provided enough info; my plumbing knowledge is definitely lacking).
I recently moved into a new apartment (in Chicago). Sometimes our water pressure suddenly dramatically decreases in the entire apartment (all faucets/showers become mere trickles, or put out no water at all) for periods of usually 5 minutes or less, but sometimes longer.
The apartment is owned by a relatively sizeable management company. When we reached out to our property manager, they sent a company to pump the pipes and clear out sediment, and when that didn't really help, they said "The building is old, and has old pipes; you just gotta deal with it, there's nothing more we can do." When pressed about what "old pipes" means, and why that causes this issue, they had no explanation.
We're guessing that this happens when someone else uses water in the apartment building (6 identical units, 3 floors). For instance, there's a noticeable effect on water pressure when we turn on a faucet and a shower at the same time.
I'd understand a normal drop in water pressure at random times in the day, but to not have any running water at all seems unreasonable to me. It happens quite frequently; basically we don't have reliable water between 7am-2pm and 7pm-11pm.
Here's some more information about the issue, in case it helps: we're on the third floor. 2 of the units in the building are AirBnBs and often aren't occupied. Apparently every fixture in our apartment is connected directly down into the main line. Management has sent out a company to pump the pipes for sediment 6 or so times in the last half year, meaning our neighbors probably have similar complaints. And again, all fixtures in the apartment are affected by the water pressure drops when they happen. Both hot and cold water is affected. Also, I believe the building is about 90-100 years old, but I'm not sure.
Our questions are as follows:

What exactly might cause something like this? We want to know so that we have something to say to management when we press further. Like what is the mechanism of this sudden decrease in water pressure? Does "pipes being old" actually make sense as an excuse, and if yes, why?
If you have a guess about the cause of the problem, how costly/difficult might it be to fix?
This is unreasonable, right? To not have running water randomly throughout in the day? Or are we actually just being whiny and this is a common issue? (I need a sanity check)

Any advice would be really appreciated. Thanks very much for your time!

that large pressure drop points to the pressure regulator, that needs replacement or adjustment, do you know where it is?

It depends on the pipe diameter, pressure, and how many faucets are open at once.  Being on the third floor does not help either.  Each faucet open at the same time drops the pressure some, worst with smaller size pipes.  If first and/or second floors are using the water at the same time, no wonder the pressure drops.  Old pipes might mean they are smaller diameter.  A new building should have large enough pipes to handle the use.

@Traveler Hi, sorry, I don't know where the pressure regulator is. If it's the pressure regulator causing the problem, does that mean that that the total pressure in the apartment/building is lower than it's supposed to be, or something? Why might the large pressure drop make you expect this problem? (Sorry for the extra questions, I want to understand so I can convince the property manager)

@crip659 Yes, it makes sense to expect some drop in water pressure, but it seems abnormal to have no running water in my entire apartment at all sometimes. Or maybe it's not abnormal, and I'm just being picky? Do you know if this a common problem? Also, I doubt all my neighbors are running all their fixtures at once or something, especially since two units are often empty. Sometimes the water is gone for only like 30 seconds, as if someone was just washing their hands or something.

It takes too much more information to know for sure.  The plumbing should be sized for that building, unless its used was changed in the past, but codes also change.  Older code might have allowed a less than perfect pressure system than today's would, or something is not quite right/simple to fix.

My guess is you are on the third floor. This problem is fairly typical of many apartment buildings especially in upstairs units. However, the low pressure you are describing is excessive and not normal.
You might ask the plumbers to measure the water pressure as it enters the building (curbside pressure) and then after the pressure reduction valve (PRV), if there is one. Usually, curb pressure is about 125 PSI plus or minus 20.
If it's much lower it could be a sign of corroded or leaking supply lines that could be the responsibility of the city/town or the apartment building owner, depending on the location.
If the curbside pressure is in a normal range and the apartment has a PRV it may be set too low to provide adequate water pressure, especially to upper floors during high usage periods. In a typical home the pressure after the PRV is in the 50 to 75 PSI range.
If it's less than that, there are things that the property owner can do to boost pressure to upper floors, including adjusting the PRV, booster pumps, etc. Whether they would is an open question.
In an older building you could have corrosion that has built up in the pipes over the years that could be part of the problem.
Edit: If you have a sillcock somewhere in your unit (clothes washer, deck) you can purchase a screw on water pressure gauge very inexpensively to measure your pressure and record the readings along with time of day to show the owner.


Thank so much for the response! If hypothetically both measurements turned out to be within a normal range, what might you expect the issue to be? Or is this basically the only reasonable cause?

If the apartment building is older with no updated plumbing, it could be the result of corrosion that has built up in the pipes over time. If you have a sillcock somewhere in your apartment, maybe for a clothes washer, you can purchase a water pressure gauge on line or in any home store that will screw on to the sillcock and permit you to get pressure readings in your unit. Record the readings and the time of day as a record for your landlord.
